# Scala API design; a service which returns a Set<I> where I is some interface (abstract/trait)

Tags: scala, covariance, scala-collections

I have asked quite a few questions about the Scala collection types and how they might actually be used. Consider how I might write some service API/implementation in Java:

```
public interface JavaProductAPI {
     public Set<IProduct> getProducts(String isin);
}
```

And now the impl:

```
public class JavaProductAPIImpl implements JavaProductAPI {
    private Map<String, Set<ProductImpl>> productsByIsin;

    public Set<IProduct> getProducts() {
        Set<ProductImpl> s = productsByIsin.get(isin);
        return s == null 
                   ? Collections.<IProduct>emptySet()
                   : Collections.<IProduct>unmodifiableSet(s);
    }

}
```

Lets say that there's a really good reason why I need to have access within the service implementation to the set of products as being of `ProductImpl`s, not `IProduct`s.

It seems that in Scala, there's no real way to achieve this whilst at the same time exlicitly returning an `scala.collection.immutable.Set` from the API access method. *Unless I don't mind returning a copy of the set*.

I'm going to assume that returning an actual copy of the data is bad practice (feel free to argue this point!):

```
val productsByIsin: Map[String, scala.collection.Set[ProductImpl]] = ...
def getProducts(isin: String): scala.collection.immutable.Set[IProduct] = {
  productsByIsin.get(isin) match {
     case Some(s) => scala.collection.immutable.Set(s toSeq :_*)
     case None => scala.collection.immutable.Set.empty
  } 
}
```

So that therefore my only real design choice is to have the API return a `scala.collection.Set` and use a read-only view:

```
val productsByIsin: Map[String, scala.collection.mutable.Set[ProductImpl]] = ...
def getProducts(isin: String): scala.collection.Set[IProduct] = {
  productsByIsin.get(isin) match {
     case Some(s) => s readOnly
     case None => scala.collection.Set.empty
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your last block of code more closely mimics the Java code you're emulating: returning a read-only view of a mutable Set.

That said, in this situation, if your backing implementation is an immutable.Set[ProductImpl] and you want to return an immutable.Set[IProduct], it's safe to cast.

```
import scala.collection._

trait IProduct
class ProductImpl extends IProduct

val productsByIsin: immutable.Map[String, immutable.Set[ProductImpl]] =
  immutable.Map.empty
def getProducts(isin: String): immutable.Set[IProduct] =
  productsByIsin.getOrElse(isin, immutable.Set.empty).asInstanceOf[immutable.Set[IProduct]]
```

Comment: But it's a meaningless cast, isn't it? This is the sort of thing that would give me an unchecked warning in Java isn't it? Is the scala compiler checking type safety?

Comment: No, the Scala compiler does not check the safety of casts. In this case it's safe. To ensure that it's safe you can do the following:

    productsByIsin.getOrElse(isin, immutable.Set.empty).map(x => x : IProduct)

which is checked by the compiler, but it also creates a new map.

Comment: Actually `Set`s in Scala are invariant only because a `Set[A]` is also an `(A => Boolean)`, and variance rules for function inheritance are exactly the opposite of those for `List`s. That's why you can take a `list: List[ProductImpl]` and assign it to `val products: List[IProduct] = list` without a cast, and although you can't do the same with invariant `Set`s, it's absolutely safe to cast it to a superclass - immutable Sets cannot be corrupted this way. An alternative and more elegant way would be to use `Set[ProductImpl]().toSet[IProduct]`, but it will create a new collection.